# Testing equality of proportions between 3 groups

Tags: r, proportion

I have two categorical variables: Risk (3 levels) and Results (2 levels). I am trying to test whether there is a significant difference in proportions of failure rates between categories. From the data it is pretty obvious there will not be a difference but how can I prove it "statistically"? Would I be using a Chi Square test?

Edit: Entered one of the values incorrectly, this has been corrected.

| Risk Level | Pass | Fail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Risk 1 | 0.763 | 0.237 |
| Risk 2 | 0.795 | 0.205 |
| Risk 3 | 0.796 | 0.204 |

| Risk Level | Pass | Fail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Risk 1 | 5663 | 1759 |
| Risk 2 | 1060 | 274 |
| Risk 3 | 164 | 42 |

Comment: How are those proportions calculated? For example, shouldn't the pass proportion for Risk 1 be 5663/(5663+1959) = 74.3% (instead of 76.3%)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, some of those proportions seem to be incorrectly calculated.

That said, you only need the raw counts to carry out hypothesis tests.

You will need to test 3 things:

- Risk level 1 vs Risk level 2
- Risk level 1 vs Risk level 3
- Risk level 2 vs Risk level 3

In R, this is straightforward to do with `prop.test()`:

```r
# 1 vs 2
# difference is statistically significant (p-value < 0.0001)
prop.test(c(5663, 1060), c(5663+1959, 1060+274))

# 1 vs 3
# difference is not statistically significant (p-value > 0.1)
prop.test(c(5663, 164), c(5663+1959, 164+42))

# 2 vs 3
# difference is not statistically significant (p-value > 0.1)
prop.test(c(1060, 164), c(1060+274, 164+42))
```

It's worth noting that, generally, you should adjust the p-values for multiple comparisons. In this case, the conclusions would be the same because the only significant p-value (Risk level 1 vs Risk level 2) is much smaller than the usual 5% or 1% thresholds.

Comment: I made a mistake when typing in the data, it has been corrected 5663/(5663+1759) should yield the correct result. This being said, thanks for that R function!